# Configuring a windows service application to not be editable by the user

Tags: .net, windows, winapi, service

I have a windows service application which is installed on a user machine and is displayed under the Service page (services.msc). I want the start options to be unconfigurable by the user (via the Services UI) as shown in the screenshot bellow (as for Windows Defender Antivirus Service):

[image: Windows Defender Antivirus Service Screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: set some security descriptor on your service via `SetServiceObjectSecurity`. say `O:BAD:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGX;;;IU)`

Comment: Hi hecate, have you tried the sample in my answer? Feel free let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @RbMM The ```SetServiceObjectSecurity()``` function is not the recommended way to resolve this requirement as it is deprecated. MSFT recommends using the ```SetNamedSecurityInfoA()``` function in aclapi.h.

Comment: @hecate - `SetServiceObjectSecurity` better and more efficient compare `SetNamedSecurityInfoW` and i recommend use exactly  `SetServiceObjectSecurity`

Answer (score 0):

@RbMm is right.

The following is an example using winapi in C++.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32")

int main()
{
    SC_HANDLE sHdl = OpenSCManager(NULL, SERVICES_ACTIVE_DATABASE, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if (sHdl == NULL)
        printf("OpenSCManager error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    SC_HANDLE serviceHdl = OpenService(sHdl, L"MyTestDirectXService", READ_CONTROL | WRITE_OWNER | WRITE_DAC);
    if (sHdl == NULL)
        printf("OpenService error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    char buf[1024];
    DWORD retLen = 0;

    // ### Query
    if(!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHdl, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, buf, sizeof(buf), &retLen))
        printf("QueryServiceObjectSecurity error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    LPWSTR strBuf = NULL;
    unsigned long strLen = 0;
    if (!ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(buf, SDDL_REVISION_1, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &strBuf, &strLen))
        printf("ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    wprintf(strBuf);

    // ### Set
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sDescriptor = {0};
    if(!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(L"O:BAD:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGX;;;IU)", SDDL_REVISION_1, &sDescriptor, NULL))
        printf("ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    if (!SetServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHdl, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sDescriptor))
        printf("SetServiceObjectSecurity error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    // ### Check
    if (!QueryServiceObjectSecurity(serviceHdl, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, buf, sizeof(buf), &retLen))
        printf("QueryServiceObjectSecurity error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    strBuf = NULL;
    strLen = 0;
    if (!ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(buf, SDDL_REVISION_1, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &strBuf, &strLen))
        printf("ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor error: %d\n", GetLastError());

    wprintf(strBuf);

    getchar();
}
```

After running above code the start option is disabled like this:

[image]

**UPDATE: Due to "[[`SetServiceObjectSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setserviceobjectsecurity) is available for use in the operating systems specified in the Requirements section. It may be altered or unavailable in subsequent versions. Instead, use the [`SetNamedSecurityInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfoa) function.]" The following is an example of using `SetNamedSecurityInfo` API.**

```
// ### Set
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sDescriptor = { 0 };
if (!ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(L"O:BAD:(A;;GA;;;SY)(A;;GRGX;;;IU)", SDDL_REVISION_1, &sDescriptor, NULL))
    printf("ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor error: %d\n", GetLastError());

char daclBuf[100];
char ownerBuf[100];
char abBuf[100];

DWORD abLen = sizeof(abBuf);
DWORD dLen = sizeof(daclBuf);
DWORD oLen = sizeof(ownerBuf);
DWORD sLen = 0;
DWORD gLen = 0;

// Only owner and DACL security information valid in String security descriptor so here set DACL and Primary Group buffer to NULL. 
BOOL returnVal = MakeAbsoluteSD(sDescriptor, abBuf, &abLen, (PACL)daclBuf, &dLen, NULL, &sLen, ownerBuf, &oLen, NULL, &gLen);
if ((!returnVal) && (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) == GetLastError())
    printf("One or more of the buffers is too small.\n");

WCHAR serviceName[] = L"MySecondService";
DWORD result = SetNamedSecurityInfo(serviceName, SE_SERVICE, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, ownerBuf, NULL, (ACL*)daclBuf, NULL);
if(ERROR_SUCCESS != result)
    printf("ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor error: %d\n", result);
```

Comment: The ```SetServiceObjectSecurity()``` function is not the recommended way to resolve this requirement as it is deprecated. MSFT recommends using the ```SetNamedSecurityInfoA()``` function in ```aclapi.h```.

Comment: @hecate Update with `SetNamedSecurityInfo` function example.